# Prepare to respond to excessive usage on personal dev AWS account

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, disaster-recovery

AWS does not provide a way to cap usage costs.  It is often pointed out that it would not be useful to shut down a commercial website in case of charges exceeding a budget, without information about the appropriate response that's only possessed by the business itself.  However, for those who want to experiment at home for learning purposes, this situation does not apply.

Prevention is a good thing, but it is impossible to prevent all accidents and attacks.  This question is about response and not prevention.

One standard suggestion is to have some means of rapidly shutting down all AWS resources in an account.

Another piece of standard advice is to make use of features like budget alerts.  As an individual citizen, it's plausible that the time to react to such an alert could be one day, or perhaps a week or more in case of illness, which could cause a very high bill.  So automation might be useful here.

**How can I solve these problems in a manner suitable for an individual developer experimenting in their own time and at their own cost?**  In particular, how can I:

1. Prepare for a rapid, well-tested, reliable response to shut down all resource usage in an AWS account
2. Trigger that response automatically (triggered by, for example, an AWS budget alert, or some other form of cost monitoring)

Some potential complications:

A. In the case of deliberate attack rather than pure user error, 1. may be complicated by the attacker making use of such features as EC2 termination protection.

B. An attacker might also make use of many different AWS services.  So, given the large and expanding AWS product range, attempting to maintain a library that deletes every type of resource (EC2 instances, RDS instances, etc.), using code that is specific to particular resource types, may be impractical.

C. This [rather old forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=572390) suggests that AWS accounts can't be closed without first cancelling all opt-in services.

Note I can't use the free tier because I want to make use of features not available in that tier.

Answer (score 1):

First off, proper security and management of root account credentials is critical. Enable MFA on all accounts, including root. Do not use the root account except for cases where absolutely necessary. Limit accounts with broad permissions. Enable CloudTrail and if desired, alert on use of elevated permissions. These sorts of actions will most certainly protect against nearly all attackers and since this is a personal account, the types of attackers who may be able to evade these controls would likely have no interest in causing an individual harm, they are more interested in large organizations.

As for accidents, what types of accidents are you thinking might happen? Do you have large compute jobs that use auto-scaling based on factors such as a queue depth? Your best action here is likely to set ASG max sizes, use CloudWatch events to monitor and re-mediate resource usage issues, or even use third party tools that deal with this type of thing.

Something to keep in mind is that AWS implements account limits that will constrain you some but for a personal account, even these limits are likely too permissive. I only have experience requesting limit increases but it might be worth asking AWS if they perform limit decreases as well.

Comment: This is interesting but does not answer this question

Answer (score 0):

You have raised concerns about excessive costs being generated due to:

- **Normal usage:** If you require the computing resources, then they are most probably of sufficient benefit to the company to warrant the cost. Therefore, excessive use should generate a warning, but you do not want to turn things off.
- **Accidental usage:** This is where an authorized person uses too many resources, such as turning on a service and forgetting to turn it off. Again, monitoring can give you a hint that this is happening. Many AWS customers create a **Sandbox Account** where they can experiment, and then use an automated script to turn off resources in this account (which is not used for real business purposes).
- **An attacker:** This is an external party sending *excessive usage* to your services (eg making many requests to your website) but without access to your actual AWS account. This could also be caused by a Denial of Service attack. There is plenty of documentation around handling DDOS-style attacks, but a safe method is to limit the maximum number of instances permitted in an Auto Scaling group.
- **Someone accessing your AWS account:** You mention an attacker making use of EC2 Termination Protection. This is an option you can apply to your own EC2 instances to prevent accidental termination. It is not something that someone outside your company would be able to control unless they have gained credentials to access your AWS Account. If you are worried about this, then active Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) on your logins.

If you are worried about excessive costs, it's worth considering what generates costs:

- **Amazon EC2 instances** are charged per hour. If you are worried about their cost, then you can Stop them, but this means they are no longer providing services to your company and customers.
- **Storage services** (eg Amazon EBS and Amazon S3) are charged based upon the amount of data stored: You most probably do *not* want to automatically delete data due to excessive costs, since the data is presumably of value to your company.
- **Database services** (eg Amazon RDS) are charged per hour. You probably don't want to turn them off because they, too, contain data of value to your company.
- Some services are charged based upon **throughput** (eg AWS API Gateway, Amazon Kinesis), but turning off such services would also impact your ability to continue providing services to your customers.

If you are talking about **personal usage of AWS that is not supplying a service to customers**, then best practice is to always **turn off services that aren't required**, such as compute and database services. AWS is an on-demand service, so you only have to pay for services that you have requested.

Also, create [Billing Alarms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-alarms.html) to alert you when you cross a certain cost threshold. These can be further broken down into [budgets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/budgets-managing-costs.html) that notify you as you approach certain spending thresholds.

**Bottom line:** Rather than focusing on system that automatically react to high expenditure and delete things, you should only run services that you currently want. Set alarms/budget to be aware of costs that exceed desired thresholds.

Comment: Since you're talking about "your company", I think you should re-read the question, concentrating on the title, the first paragraph, and the section in bold.

Comment: You suggest "turn off services that aren't required".  Some additional info: I would like to use EC2 GPU, which I think would leave plenty of room for .  In fact after writing this question I ran into a web form requesting access to GPU, which requests 'company name' etc. I guess amazon have just never seen the need to spend much development effort on encouraging learning by developers outside of work, as first mover in this market, free tier notwithstanding.

Comment: Are you really saying that even (preemptively) turning off all services (except EC2) is going to be practical for me?  This suprises me, since AWS offers many services, and it's my impression that they were by and large developed by separate teams and therefore require significant effort to limit or disable each one.